# Why was my friend's frog killed?

Tags: lateral-thinking

> My friend's frog was a very good jumper. And the frog was very good at maths, but he was killed by someone, why and by whom ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He saw an advertisement for the Adder society. Because he was a good jumper and liked maths, he jumped to the conclusion that it was about the addition operator in maths and decided to go along, thinking that he would love the opportunity to perform some addition operations. When he arrived at the group, it was actually the meet-up group for the venomous British snake species named Adder. Thus, upon arriving he was eaten.

Comment: This answer made me like the question even more!  Don't get why so many of these lateral-thinking puzzles are disliked so much...  I guess they appear a bit broad by nature...?  +1

Comment: I dislike questions like this because they’re too much like “guess what I’m thinking”.  Like “I’m thinking of a number; what is it?”  Like “I’m thinking of a story; how does it end?” — like “Why did the chicken cross the road?” You can’t ***solve*** it; you have to try, as I said, to guess what the OP is thinking.  There’s no ***right*** answer; you have to try to find ***an*** answer that fits.  It seems too much like breaking down a door rather than picking the lock or figuring out the combination. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  One could just as well answer this question with «As a baby, he was called “Niño”.  As he grew up, because like liked mathematics so much, people started calling him “Nine”.  Then one day he ran into seven foxes.  And the seven ate Nine.»   or   «He was doing a proof while standing on a cliff, and he jumped to a conclusion.»  Those aren’t wrong, they’re just not what the OP was thinking.

Comment: @PeregrineRook what i thought was completely different , see comment in question..

Comment: I’m not sure what comment you’re referring to, but it sounds like you’re just making it worse.  If you post a question with an answer in mind, and then you accept a different answer, that proves that it’s not a ***puzzle***, where the goal is to find ***the** answer*, but a contest to come up with a story that pleases the OP (you) the most.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the frog was killed by

> Air

Because

> As he was a very good jumper, the frog, as a *tadpole*, worked hard on his maths and achieved a super jump out of the friend's aquarium, ensuing oxygen deprivation and death.